# Regex expression to delete all ocurrences of a pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an html text and I have to delete all styles on it, for example:

```
let myString= "<div style='color: red;'>Hello world</div><p>Some text here</p><div style='border: 0px;'>hello world 2!</div>";
```

In this text I want to delete all occurrences that start with style=' and finish on ', so I'm removinig all styles from my text, so any word could between style= and ' how would be the regex for this.

```
let formatedString = myString.replace(regexHere, '');
```

The result should be:

```
<div>Hello world</div><p>Some text here</p><div>hello world 2!</div>
```

**Why is not duplicate:**
The suggested post is about tags, mine is about "params" inside a tag, so for a regex's newbie (like me) is different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: please read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/220949

Answer (score 2):

You can use  [`style='[^']*'`](https://regex101.com/r/ftP8qG/1)

- `style='` matches `style='` literally
- `[^']*` matches anything but `'` 0 or more times
- `'` matches `'` literally

**Demo:**

```js
let myString= "<div style='color: red;'>Hello world</div><p>Some text here</p><div style='border: 0px;'>hello world 2!</div>";
let formatedString = myString.replace(/ style='[^']*'/g, '');
console.log(formatedString);
```

Comment: What happens if we use your suggestion to parse this very StackOverflow page? ;)